# How do I access SharePoint web services behind a Windows-based-authentication or ISA server?

Tags: web-services, windows-authentication

I want to access sharepoint webservices behind a windows based authentication/ ISA server so that I can getallitems of a list.

I been looking for a tutorial to do this or come up with my own logic but no success. However I found this tutorial which does what I want, but for forms authentication:

[Form Based authentication tutorial](http://sharepointificate.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/accessing-sharepoint-webservices-behind.html)

I actually want to build a Windows 7 gadget, so all I can use is:

- HTML
- Script
- SOAP/XML/XHR

Here's a blog post that does the same thing, but with no authentication at all:

[Jquery $.ajax SOAP webservices](http://leonidius2010.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/98/#comment-30)

Comment: Man you really are having problems with this Windows 7 gadget... :P

Comment: LOL and you know it :D, i really wanna do it, everyone saying i can't do it, its impoossible, but i beleive if you can do something with User Interface then you can easily do that thing with Coding :)

Comment: I'd replace easily with theoretical

Comment: dunno what does that means, Per Jakobsen lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you can do something with User Interface then you can easily do
>   that thing with Coding

But building a Gadget the way you are trying is not really coding.

Here is a tutorial on [how to build a gadget using C#](http://www.nikhilk.net/SidebarGadgets.aspx). Once you have that down you would then need to learn how to use the SharePoint web services.

Then you would [generate a proxy class](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/consuming-a-web-service-in-c/) from the list web service (http:///_vti_bin/Lists.asmx.).

Then you would need to learn to call the web service and [parse the returned data](http://apartha77.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-sharepoint-web-service-listasmx.html). You could do this all with authentication because you are using C#.

Comment: Nice this seems like a better way to go since you can use C#. I was assuming only HTML/JS/CSS could be used.

Comment: I will give it a go soon :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is.. you can't really authenticate the user using JavaScript. At least, not like in C# where you can just provide credentials or use the user's DefaultNetworkCredentials.

The only thing I can think of to get this to work is by loading a page from the SharePoint server. Hopefully, since it is Windows auth, the page will load automatically with the current user's credentials.

Maybe try creating a HTML page that is calling the SharePoint webservices on the SharePoint server (in a document library for example) and then load that page in an IFRAME in your gadget.

Comment: this list is doing exactly what i want, but they dont do it for SSL/HTTP :) 

http://datapolis.com/products/sharepointlistgadget.aspx

I think I need to use a dll, and a COM object :)